# How to create thumbnail or jpeg image from a video in Google Cloud Storage server-side with Java

Tags: java, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How do you take a video from Google Cloud Storage and generate a jpeg image from one of its frames?

The frame can be used as a thumbnail for the video. Or by getting frames at periodic times that can be used to make preview frames when scrubbing the video.

I like to do this with Java server-side (on Google App Engine). This is the code I can use to get the Blob of the video in Google Cloud Storage. What are my options after I do that?

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(BUCKET, OBJECT_NAME);
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
```

I'm looking for a fast and lightweight solution because this will be run server-side in Google App Engine.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Comment: @DougStevenson I reworded my question. I wasn't asking if it is possible but how do I actually do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a rather broad question for Stack Overflow. It's expected that you make an attempt at solving the problem, then post when you have a specific problem that you're stuck on with your code.

Comment: Well besides the image's api there really isn't much help out there. This is why I am asking here... Is there a backend service I am unaware of? or some other method?

Comment: The first thing to do would be some web searches for the tools you think you'll need to accomplish this rather complex task.

Comment: A quick Google search seems to show this as a candidate ... http://jcodec.org/

Comment: This should have been closed as Too broad years ago. Can't do it now that the bounty is active.

Comment: @Jorn How is this too broad..? Seems like an important question to me.

Comment: This is StackOverflow. We have rules ;-) Whether or not a question is interesting or important isn't relevant for it being on-topic. In this case, it's more of a "how do I even start doing this" than a "how do I fix this specific issue", and we consider that too broad. I don't make the rules, sorry.

Comment: @Jorn There are a lot of questions like that on SO that get a lot of answers and up votes. I have provided a starting point with my question. It isn't a completely out of the blue question. There is context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the answer of @VonC is excellent, I would recommend you using the functionality provided by the [Transcoder API](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview) instead of a custom solution.

Specifically the Transcoder API gives you the capability of [generating a spritesheet of video frames](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/generate-spritesheet).

As indicated in the documentation, you have two options for generating the thumbnails:

> You have two options for generating the spritesheet:
>
> - [Generate a set number of thumbnail images](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/generate-spritesheet#generate_set_number_of_images) distributed evenly across the
>   input video timeline.
> - [Generate a thumbnail image periodically](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/generate-spritesheet#generate_image_periodically), that is, every n seconds, across
>   the input video timeline.

The API provides SDK for different programing languages, [Java](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/generate-spritesheet#create-job-set-number-images-spritesheet-java) ([2](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/generate-spritesheet#create-job-periodic-images-spritesheet-java)) among them. [This related example](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/samples/transcoder-create-job-with-set-number-images-spritesheet?hl=en#transcoder_create_job_with_set_number_images_spritesheet-java) could be of help as well. For reference:

```java
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.AudioStream;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.CreateJobRequest;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.ElementaryStream;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.Input;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.Job;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.JobConfig;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.LocationName;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.MuxStream;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.Output;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.SpriteSheet;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.TranscoderServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.VideoStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CreateJobWithSetNumberImagesSpritesheet {

  public static final String smallSpritesheetFilePrefix = "small-sprite-sheet";
  public static final String largeSpritesheetFilePrefix = "large-sprite-sheet";
  public static final String spritesheetFileSuffix = "0000000000.jpeg";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "my-project-id";
    String location = "us-central1";
    String inputUri = "gs://my-bucket/my-video-file";
    String outputUri = "gs://my-bucket/my-output-folder/";

    createJobWithSetNumberImagesSpritesheet(projectId, location, inputUri, outputUri);
  }

  // Creates a job from an ad-hoc configuration and generates two spritesheets from the input video.
  // Each spritesheet contains a set number of images.
  public static void createJobWithSetNumberImagesSpritesheet(
      String projectId, String location, String inputUri, String outputUri) throws IOException {
    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    try (TranscoderServiceClient transcoderServiceClient = TranscoderServiceClient.create()) {

      VideoStream videoStream0 =
          VideoStream.newBuilder()
              .setH264(
                  VideoStream.H264CodecSettings.newBuilder()
                      .setBitrateBps(550000)
                      .setFrameRate(60)
                      .setHeightPixels(360)
                      .setWidthPixels(640))
              .build();

      AudioStream audioStream0 =
          AudioStream.newBuilder().setCodec("aac").setBitrateBps(64000).build();

      // Generates a 10x10 spritesheet of small images from the input video. To preserve the source
      // aspect ratio, you should set the spriteWidthPixels field or the spriteHeightPixels
      // field, but not both.
      SpriteSheet smallSpriteSheet =
          SpriteSheet.newBuilder()
              .setFilePrefix(smallSpritesheetFilePrefix)
              .setSpriteHeightPixels(32)
              .setSpriteWidthPixels(64)
              .setColumnCount(10)
              .setRowCount(10)
              .setTotalCount(100)
              .build();

      // Generates a 10x10 spritesheet of larger images from the input video.
      SpriteSheet largeSpriteSheet =
          SpriteSheet.newBuilder()
              .setFilePrefix(largeSpritesheetFilePrefix)
              .setSpriteHeightPixels(72)
              .setSpriteWidthPixels(128)
              .setColumnCount(10)
              .setRowCount(10)
              .setTotalCount(100)
              .build();

      JobConfig config =
          JobConfig.newBuilder()
              .addInputs(Input.newBuilder().setKey("input0").setUri(inputUri))
              .setOutput(Output.newBuilder().setUri(outputUri))
              .addElementaryStreams(
                  ElementaryStream.newBuilder()
                      .setKey("video_stream0")
                      .setVideoStream(videoStream0))
              .addElementaryStreams(
                  ElementaryStream.newBuilder()
                      .setKey("audio_stream0")
                      .setAudioStream(audioStream0))
              .addMuxStreams(
                  MuxStream.newBuilder()
                      .setKey("sd")
                      .setContainer("mp4")
                      .addElementaryStreams("video_stream0")
                      .addElementaryStreams("audio_stream0")
                      .build())
              .addSpriteSheets(smallSpriteSheet) // Add the spritesheet config to the job config
              .addSpriteSheets(largeSpriteSheet) // Add the spritesheet config to the job config
              .build();

      var createJobRequest =
          CreateJobRequest.newBuilder()
              .setJob(
                  Job.newBuilder()
                      .setInputUri(inputUri)
                      .setOutputUri(outputUri)
                      .setConfig(config)
                      .build())
              .setParent(LocationName.of(projectId, location).toString())
              .build();

      // Send the job creation request and process the response.
      Job job = transcoderServiceClient.createJob(createJobRequest);
      System.out.println("Job: " + job.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

The input of the transcoder Job is obtained from Cloud Storage.

As a consequence, in order to start the transcoding process with this code probably the way to go could be defining a [Cloud Function that responds to the creation] - object finalize event - of a video](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage).

You can find an example of a function that handles this type of events in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage).

```java
import com.google.cloud.functions.CloudEventsFunction;
import com.google.events.cloud.storage.v1.StorageObjectData;
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
import io.cloudevents.CloudEvent;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class HelloGcs implements CloudEventsFunction {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloGcs.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void accept(CloudEvent event) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    logger.info("Event: " + event.getId());
    logger.info("Event Type: " + event.getType());

    if (event.getData() == null) {
      logger.warning("No data found in cloud event payload!");
      return;
    }

    String cloudEventData = new String(event.getData().toBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    StorageObjectData.Builder builder = StorageObjectData.newBuilder();
    JsonFormat.parser().merge(cloudEventData, builder);
    StorageObjectData data = builder.build();

    logger.info("Bucket: " + data.getBucket());
    logger.info("File: " + data.getName());
    logger.info("Metageneration: " + data.getMetageneration());
    logger.info("Created: " + data.getTimeCreated());
    logger.info("Updated: " + data.getUpdated());
  }
}
```

The final code in the function could be similar to this (forgive for any inaccuracy, I just try combining the two samples):

```java
import com.google.cloud.functions.CloudEventsFunction;
import com.google.events.cloud.storage.v1.StorageObjectData;
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
import io.cloudevents.CloudEvent;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.AudioStream;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.CreateJobRequest;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.ElementaryStream;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.Input;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.Job;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.JobConfig;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.LocationName;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.MuxStream;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.Output;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.SpriteSheet;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.TranscoderServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.VideoStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TranscodingFunction implements CloudEventsFunction {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloGcs.class.getName());

  public static final String smallSpritesheetFilePrefix = "small-sprite-sheet";
  public static final String largeSpritesheetFilePrefix = "large-sprite-sheet";
  public static final String spritesheetFileSuffix = "0000000000.jpeg";

  String projectId = "my-project-id";
  String location = "us-central1";

  @Override
  public void accept(CloudEvent event) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    logger.info("Event: " + event.getId());
    logger.info("Event Type: " + event.getType());

    if (event.getData() == null) {
      logger.warning("No data found in cloud event payload!");
      return;
    }

    String cloudEventData = new String(event.getData().toBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    StorageObjectData.Builder builder = StorageObjectData.newBuilder();
    JsonFormat.parser().merge(cloudEventData, builder);
    StorageObjectData data = builder.build();

    logger.info("Bucket: " + data.getBucket());
    logger.info("File: " + data.getName());
    logger.info("Metageneration: " + data.getMetageneration());
    logger.info("Created: " + data.getTimeCreated());
    logger.info("Updated: " + data.getUpdated());

    String inputUri = data.getBucket() + data.getName();
    String outputUri = "gs://my-bucket/my-output-folder/";

    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    try (TranscoderServiceClient transcoderServiceClient = TranscoderServiceClient.create()) {

      VideoStream videoStream0 =
          VideoStream.newBuilder()
              .setH264(
                  VideoStream.H264CodecSettings.newBuilder()
                      .setBitrateBps(550000)
                      .setFrameRate(60)
                      .setHeightPixels(360)
                      .setWidthPixels(640))
              .build();

      AudioStream audioStream0 =
          AudioStream.newBuilder().setCodec("aac").setBitrateBps(64000).build();

      // Generates a 10x10 spritesheet of small images from the input video. To preserve the source
      // aspect ratio, you should set the spriteWidthPixels field or the spriteHeightPixels
      // field, but not both.
      SpriteSheet smallSpriteSheet =
          SpriteSheet.newBuilder()
              .setFilePrefix(smallSpritesheetFilePrefix)
              .setSpriteHeightPixels(32)
              .setSpriteWidthPixels(64)
              .setColumnCount(10)
              .setRowCount(10)
              .setTotalCount(100)
              .build();

      // Generates a 10x10 spritesheet of larger images from the input video.
      SpriteSheet largeSpriteSheet =
          SpriteSheet.newBuilder()
              .setFilePrefix(largeSpritesheetFilePrefix)
              .setSpriteHeightPixels(72)
              .setSpriteWidthPixels(128)
              .setColumnCount(10)
              .setRowCount(10)
              .setTotalCount(100)
              .build();

      JobConfig config =
          JobConfig.newBuilder()
              .addInputs(Input.newBuilder().setKey("input0").setUri(inputUri))
              .setOutput(Output.newBuilder().setUri(outputUri))
              .addElementaryStreams(
                  ElementaryStream.newBuilder()
                      .setKey("video_stream0")
                      .setVideoStream(videoStream0))
              .addElementaryStreams(
                  ElementaryStream.newBuilder()
                      .setKey("audio_stream0")
                      .setAudioStream(audioStream0))
              .addMuxStreams(
                  MuxStream.newBuilder()
                      .setKey("sd")
                      .setContainer("mp4")
                      .addElementaryStreams("video_stream0")
                      .addElementaryStreams("audio_stream0")
                      .build())
              .addSpriteSheets(smallSpriteSheet) // Add the spritesheet config to the job config
              .addSpriteSheets(largeSpriteSheet) // Add the spritesheet config to the job config
              .build();

      var createJobRequest =
          CreateJobRequest.newBuilder()
              .setJob(
                  Job.newBuilder()
                      .setInputUri(inputUri)
                      .setOutputUri(outputUri)
                      .setConfig(config)
                      .build())
              .setParent(LocationName.of(projectId, location).toString())
              .build();

      // Send the job creation request and process the response.
      Job job = transcoderServiceClient.createJob(createJobRequest);
      System.out.println("Job: " + job.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

The event trigger and the function should be properly configured.

Please, note that the transcoding job is asynchronous, you may need some additional work to read the results.

Although probably more complex, but based in this idea, [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automate-your-vod-transcoding-at-scale-with-gcp-part-1-87503fdd3a9f) and the [companion one](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automate-your-vod-transcoding-at-scale-with-gcp-part-2-b1da0e57823d) could be of help.

Comment: That seems better than my custom solution indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @VonC. Thank you very much! I don't know if the solution is better, but it is true that the API is conceived for that type of processing, and it could be a solution easier and simpler to implement than a custom one. I upvoted your answer as well, as I said, it is a very good one.

Comment: Both your and @VonC 's answers are excellent. They each take a different but useful approach. Awarding the bounty is going to be hard but since I asked for a fast and lightweight solution, I will award it to you. But I will be testing both. One thing to consider about the Transcoder API is the cost (https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/pricing). The question will come down to is it cheaper using VonC's solution by using GAE computation time or using the Transcoder API with it's API costs. I don't have enough time to test this, as the bounty must be awarded soon.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Micro. Thank you very much: yes, as I said, using the Transcoder API could be the easiest way to implement the proposed use case, in the end the API is built for that purpose, but the solutions proposed by @VonC are very good as well. Regarding the price, I think it is difficult to say as well: the GCP documentation is quite confusing when explaining the prices of the Transcoder API. Sorry, I searched for the exact information about the cost of generating the spritesheets but I was unable to; I event perform some basic tests without incurring actually in costs.

Comment: In any way, although I am not sure of the exact amount, from my experience the cost of generating the spritesheets was minimal. It will depend on the actual hw platform you choose of course, but probably the amount of computing power necessary to perform the task in GAE will make it more expensive. The cost of Cloud Storage, network, etc, should be roughly the same in both cases. I am sorry for not being able to give you a more precise information about the exact costs @Micro.

Comment: @jccampanero No problem at all. Figuring out the pricing of these things isn't easy. The only real way to do it is to implement it at scale and look at the big numbers. I also think that trying to do this on your own in GAE will probably be more expensive but again, it always depends on what your doing and how big the input is.

Comment: Thank you very much @Micro. Yes, I absolutely agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a thumbnail or JPEG image from a video stored in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) involves a few steps and may require a bit more than just Java to accomplish. Typically, you'd use a media processing software like FFmpeg to generate frames from a video.

However, using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) or similar tools directly in App Engine can be tricky since you are restricted in terms of installing and executing third-party binary files in the App Engine environment. Therefore, the typical solution involves using Google Cloud Functions or Google Cloud Run to execute the FFmpeg commands and App Engine to trigger these functions.

That should mean:

- Uploading the Video to Google Cloud Storage. That could be done from your application running on App Engine.
- Creating a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) or a [Cloud Run instance](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run) that listens for the upload event. The function would use a tool like `FFmpeg` to generate an image from the video. It would save the image back to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
- triggering the Cloud Function/Cloud Run instance, when the video is uploaded.

Here is a Python example of a Google Cloud Function that does this (it is not Java, but it gives you an idea of what the function would need to do).
(inspired from [`brown-mida/elvo/etl/processed_dag.py#to_public_png()`](https://github.com/brown-mida/elvo/blob/430453f0b71eb77f108a190cdb28b0ab3f70b631/etl/processed_dag.py#L28-L48))
The function is triggered when a new video is uploaded, it uses FFmpeg to grab an image from the video, then it stores the image in the bucket:

```py
import os
import tempfile
from google.cloud import storage
import subprocess

def generate_thumbnail(data, context):
    file_data = data
    file_name = file_data['name']
    bucket_name = file_data['bucket']

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

    _, temp_local_filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
    
    blob.download_to_filename(temp_local_filename)
    print(f"Video downloaded to {temp_local_filename}.")

    thumbnail_file = temp_local_filename + '.png'
    
    command = f"ffmpeg -i {temp_local_filename} -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 {thumbnail_file}"
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

    print(f"Thumbnail created at {thumbnail_file}.")

    thumbnail_blob = bucket.blob(file_name + '.png')
    thumbnail_blob.upload_from_filename(thumbnail_file)

    print(f"Thumbnail uploaded to {bucket_name}/{file_name}.png")

    os.remove(temp_local_filename)
    os.remove(thumbnail_file)
```

With that setup, the work of generating the thumbnail is offloaded from your Java App Engine service to the Cloud Function. That would provide a scalable solution to create video thumbnails without using resources from your App Engine service.
You can create Cloud Functions using various runtime environments like Python, Node.js, Java, Go, .NET, etc. Python was used here because FFmpeg interaction is a bit more straightforward.

Warning: this type of operation might result in additional costs due to the usage of Cloud Functions/Cloud Run and the extra storage requirements for the images generated.

Finally, if you need to stick with Java and use App Engine only, consider using [App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible), which would let you use FFmpeg or another tool.

---

Creating a Cloud Function or Cloud Run instance in Java to do this task is more complex than using a scripting language like Python because Java does not have native support for running shell commands like `FFmpeg`.

However, creating a Cloud Function or Cloud Run instance with FFmpeg is possible with Java if you use a custom Dockerfile and run a shell command from Java. That is typically done in a Cloud Run instance rather than a Cloud Function because Cloud Run allows you to use a custom Dockerfile to include FFmpeg in the runtime.

For instance, here is a simple Java application that uses FFmpeg to extract a frame from a video. That could be used as the base for your Cloud Run instance.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String videoPath = "/path/to/video.mp4";
        String imagePath = "/path/to/output.png";

        // That command extracts a frame from the 1st second of the video
        String command = String.format("ffmpeg -i %s -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 %s", videoPath, imagePath);

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Frame extracted successfully!");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that the Java process will need to have the necessary permissions to execute the FFmpeg command and access the files.)

In a real-world application, this should be wrapped in a web server (like Spring Boot) to handle HTTP requests and responses. The video would be downloaded from Google Cloud Storage to a temporary file, the FFmpeg command would be run to generate the frame, then the image file would be uploaded back to Google Cloud Storage. You would also need to include error handling and logging to ensure the process works smoothly, and any issues can be diagnosed.

---

As commented, you do have [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/), a pure Java implementation of video encoders and decoders, including functionality for generating frames from a video. You can certainly use it on Google App Engine Standard Environment.

That is how you can use JCodec to extract a frame from a video:

```java
import org.jcodec.api.JCodecException;
import org.jcodec.api.awt.AWTFrameGrab;
import org.jcodec.common.FileChannelWrapper;
import org.jcodec.common.NIOUtils;
import org.jcodec.common.io.SeekableByteChannel;
import org.jcodec.scale.AWTUtil;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FrameGrabber {

    public static void getFrame(String videoPath, String framePath, double frameNumber) throws IOException, JCodecException {
        SeekableByteChannel bc = null;
        try {
            bc = NIOUtils.readableFileChannel(videoPath);
            BufferedImage frame = AWTFrameGrab.getFrame(new FileChannelWrapper(bc), frameNumber);
            BufferedImage rgbFrame = AWTUtil.toBufferedImage(frame);
            ImageIO.write(rgbFrame, "png", new File(framePath));
        } finally {
            NIOUtils.closeQuietly(bc);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String videoPath = "path/to/your/video.mp4";
            String framePath = "path/to/save/frame.png";
            getFrame(videoPath, framePath, 1);
            System.out.println("Frame extracted successfully!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You would use the `getFrame` method, which opens the video file, extracts a frame at a specified position (the frame number is a double indicating seconds into the video), converts the frame to an RGB image, and saves the frame to a file.

You would need to adapt this code to work with your `Blob` object, possibly by first downloading the blob to a temporary file in your App Engine environment, then using JCodec to extract the frame, and finally uploading the resulting image file back to Google Cloud Storage. Note that Google App Engine has restrictions on the file system access, but you can use the temporary directory (`/tmp`) to write files.

Since decoding video frames is a CPU intensive task and might take a bit of time depending on the size and length of the video, you need to be careful with the App Engine instance's resources and execution time limit.